# Why do my Perl tests fail with use encoding 'utf8'?

Tags: perl, testing, utf-8

I'm puzzled with this test script:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use encoding 'utf8';
use Test::More 'no_plan';

ok('áá' =~ m/á/, 'ok direct match');

my $re = qr{á};
ok('áá' =~ m/$re/, 'ok qr-based match');

like('áá', $re, 'like qr-based match');
```

The three tests fail, but I was expecting that the `use encoding 'utf8'` would upgrade both the literal `áá` and the `qr`-based regexps to utf8 strings, and thus passing the tests.

If I remove the `use encoding` line the tests pass as expected, but I can't figure it out why would they fail in `utf8` mode.

I'm using perl 5.8.8 on Mac OS X (system version).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Do not** use the [`encoding` pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/encoding.html). It’s broken. (Juerd Waalboer gave a great talk where he mentioned this at YAPC::EU 2k8.)

It does at least two things at once that do not belong together:

1. It specifies an encoding for your source file.
2. It specifies an encoding for your file input/output.

And to add injury to insult it also does #1 in a broken fashion: it reinterprets `\xNN` sequences as being undecoded octets as opposed to treating them like codepoints, and decodes them, preventing you from being able to express characters outside the encoding you specified and making your source code mean different things depending on the encoding. That’s just astonishingly wrong.

Write your source code in ASCII or UTF-8 only. In the latter case, **the [`utf8` pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html)** is the correct thing to use. If you don’t want to use UTF-8, but you do want to include non-ASCII charcters, escape or decode them explicitly.

And use I/O layers explicitly or set them using **the [`open` pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html)** to have I/O automatically transcoded properly.

Comment: In the past I always used `use utf8` and sometime in the last year or so, I saw somewhere that `use utf8` was broken and I should use `use encoding 'utf8'`.

It seems that I need to revisit the whole issue again...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It works fine on my computer (on perl 5.10). Maybe you should try replacing that `use encoding 'utf8'` with `use utf8`.

What version of perl are you using? I think older versions had bugs with UTF-8 in regexps.

Comment: I also changed `use encoding 'utf8'` to `use utf8` and it worked for me on 5.8.8 Linux

Answer (score 2):

The [Test::More documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Test/More.html) contains a fix for this issue, which I just found today (and this entry shows higher in the googles).

> **utf8 / "Wide character in print"**
>
> If you use utf8 or other non-ASCII characters with Test::More you might get a "Wide character in print" warning. Using binmode STDOUT,  ":utf8" will not fix it. Test::Builder (which powers Test::More) duplicates STDOUT and STDERR. So any changes to them, including changing their output disciplines, will not be seem by Test::More. The work around is to change the filehandles used by Test::Builder directly.
>
> ```
> my $builder = Test::More->builder;
> binmode $builder->output,         ":utf8";
> binmode $builder->failure_output, ":utf8";
> binmode $builder->todo_output,    ":utf8";
> ```

I added this bit of boilerplate to my testing code and it works a charm.