# How can I embede chinese characters in my Perl source?

Tags: perl, unicode

In my script I need to "qw" some chinese character into a string .  when I run the script ,
perl conplains that there is unrecognized character in the script .  Although I know it must related to encode related stuff , but I don't know how to solve  it . so turn to  you for help .

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Embedding literal strings in Perl source code is easy. Use the `utf8` pragma. ([Do not use the `encoding` pragma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492838/why-do-my-perl-tests-fail-with-use-encoding-utf8/493508#493508), it is highly problematic.)

```
use utf8;
my $perl_string = '你好，张ＨＹ';
```

Your text editor must save this file as UTF-8, too.

Then, if you want to output Perl strings, you must encode them first, see [perlunitut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html) and [perlunifaq](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunifaq.html).

```
use Encode qw(encode);
use Encode::HanExtra;
# for example, printing to STDOUT

print encode('UTF-8', $perl_string); # in a Linux environment
print encode('GB18030', $perl_string); # in a Windows environment
```

I also want to advise you that since the year 2006 support for the national standard [GB18030](http://www.gb18030.com/) is mandatory for all software products in the PRC - you have to install [Encode::HanExtra](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Encode-HanExtra) from CPAN.