# How do I encode characters into numeric character reference format in Perl?

Tags: perl, utf-8, decode, encode, perl-module

I found this sample script from [How can I guess the encoding of a string in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970660/how-can-i-guess-the-encoding-of-a-string-in-perl)

```
#!C:\perl\bin
use utf8;
use Encode qw(encode PERLQQ XMLCREF);
my $string = 'This year I went to 北京 Perl workshop.';
#print encode('ascii', $string, PERLQQ);
# This year I went to \x{5317}\x{4eac} Perl workshop.
print encode('ascii', $string, XMLCREF); # This year I went to &#x5317;&#x4eac; Perl workshop.
```

After having a test I found the encoded output result to be:

```
This year I went to \x{71fa9} Perl workshop.
This year I went to &#x71fa9; Perl workshop.
```

Looks like the result is different from the one author shows us above in the sample code.

I wonder how could I encode a character string and make its output in the [numeric character reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference) format (`&#xHHHH;`), for example when:

```
my $string = 'This year I went to 北京 Perl workshop.';
```

the encoded output would be:

```
This year I went to &#x5317;&#x4eac; Perl workshop.
```

Comment: my test  output look like this This year I went to & #x71fa9; Perl workshop.

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of the answer linked in the question.

---

You made a simple mistake, you saved the Perl program in GB18030. When it contains `use utf8;`, you must [save it in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951613/how-to-match-chinese-character-using-perls-regex#comment-1870809) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string =~ s/[^\0-\377]/ sprintf '&#x%04x;', ord($&) /ge
```

Find each character in `$string` not in the range 0-255 (i.e., any wide characters), and replace it with the value of the expression  `sprintf '&#x%04x;', ord($&)`, where `$&` is the wide character that was matched.

```
use utf8;
$string = "This year I went to \x{5317}\x{4eac} Perl workshop.";
$string =~ s/[^\0-\377]/ sprintf '&#x%04x;', ord($&) /ge;
print $string;
```

Produces:

```
This year I went to &#x5317;&#x4eac; Perl workshop.
```