# Detect chinese character using perl?

Tags: perl, split, detect, cjk

Is there any way to detect Chinese characters using Perl? And is there any way on how to split Chinese characters with symbol dot '.' perfectly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951613/how-to-match-chinese-character-using-perls-regex

Answer (score 9):

Depends on your particular notion of what is a Chinese character. Perhaps you're looking for `/\p{Script=Hani}/`, but if we want to cast our net wide, the following regex pattern will match stuff that occurs in Chinese writing. Restrict if necessary.

```
use 5.014;
/
    (?: \p{Block=CJK_Compatibility}
    |   \p{Block=CJK_Compatibility_Forms}
    |   \p{Block=CJK_Compatibility_Ideographs}
    |   \p{Block=CJK_Compatibility_Ideographs_Supplement}
    |   \p{Block=CJK_Radicals_Supplement}
    |   \p{Block=CJK_Strokes}
    |   \p{Block=CJK_Symbols_And_Punctuation}
    |   \p{Block=CJK_Unified_Ideographs}
    |   \p{Block=CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_A}
    |   \p{Block=CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_B}
    |   \p{Block=CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_C}
    )
/x;
```

---

Yes, `.` matches one character. The empty pattern for [split](http://p3rl.org/split) DWYM:

```
use utf8;
split //, '冰淇淋'
# returns ('冰', '淇', '淋')
```

Comment: How about if 冰.淇. ,but I just want to split out the last dot not all dot in the whole words?

Comment: PerlDoc page on this technique: http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html#Properties-accessible-through-%5Cp%7B%7D-and-%5CP%7B%7D