# How to detect Chinese character using Perl?

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect chinese character using perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937087/detect-chinese-character-using-perl)

Is there any way to detect Chinese character using Perl?

And is there any way on how to split Chinese character with symbol dot '.' perfectly?

Comment: Detect chinese character using perl? in webapps.stackexchange.com is post by me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use utf8;

my $str = "a银行系统时间表";
$str =~ m/(\p{Han}+)/;
print join('.', split(//, $1));
```

return

```
银.行.系.统.时.间.表
```

PS: I can't read/speak chinese so I have no idea about what $str says. If it's rude soz ^^

Comment: In general, you can look up names of scripts in the perluniprops documentation

Comment: It says "Schedule for the banking system" so don't worry. Also China usually uses 。 for punctuation rather than '.' at the end of a sentence.

Comment: @Rincewind42 oki thx. Yeah it was came from HSBC website ^^

Comment: well, I need to split 银.行.系.统.时.间.表 to 银行系统时间表.