# How to match Chinese characters in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

How to match Chinese characters in Perl? Why

```
$ perl -e 'if ( "中国" =~ /\p{Han}/ ) { print "!"}'
$
```

doesn't work?

Comment: Are you using utf8? `use utf8`?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951613/how-to-match-chinese-character-using-perls-regex

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your source code is UTF-8, you need to use `use utf8;`. If it isn't UTF-8, the source couldn't possibly have any Han characters in it.

```
$ perl -le'use utf8; if ( "中国" =~ /\p{Han}/ ) { print "!" }'
!
```