# How do I write Arabic in Perl source files?

Tags: perl, arabic

I need to write Arabic words as labels inside a `.pm` file. It is not working for me. I tried ASCII letters and they worked. Is there a better way to do so?

I tried something like:

```
<span dir="rtl" lang="ar">&#1593;&#1585;&#1576;&#1610;</span>
```

Comment: That is HTML, not Perl. The best way is probably "Move your HTML to a template file and get it out of your program logic".

Comment: @David: what does this template file has to be? and how I would include it inside perl file?

Comment: There are a number of template mechanisms available for Perl. I would use Template-Toolkit (http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Template / http://template-toolkit.org/). Other options include HTML::Template (http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::Template)

Comment: Also see [How can I embede chinese characters in my Perl source?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1945221#1945756). This works: `use utf8; $string = 'عربي';`

Comment: I have an arabic example in the Unicode chapter of _Effective Perl Programming_. :)

Answer (score 10):

```
use utf8;
```

tells Perl that your program is written with utf-8 encoding. Do not use [encoding pragma](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?encoding) - it is broken.