# How can I use the range operator '..' to create a utf-8 alphabet?

Tags: perl

Is there a way to create a UTF-8 alphabet array using the Perl '..' operator?

For example, this one won't work:

```
$ cat t.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;
use encoding 'utf8';

print Dumper('А'..'Я'); # not working!
print Dumper('А','Б','В'); # ...works fine! but needs to be filling letter by letter

$ perl t.pl
$VAR1 = "\x{410}";
$VAR1 = "\x{410}";
$VAR2 = "\x{411}";
$VAR3 = "\x{412}";

$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
```

Any advice?

Comment: Advice about the encoding pragma: http://stackoverflow.com/q/492838#493508

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is mentioned - briefly - in the [range operator docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators).
You need to use the [ord](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ord.html) and [chr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chr.html) functions:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;
use encoding 'utf8';

my @arry = map { chr } ord( 'А' ) .. ord( 'Я' );
for my $letter ( @arry ) {
    print "$letter ";
}
print "\n";
```

Output:

```
А Б В Г Д Е Ж З И Й К Л М Н О П Р С Т У Ф Х Ц Ч Ш Щ Ъ Ы Ь Э Ю Я
```

The result you see arises because the initial value of the range isn't part of a 'magical' sequence (a non-empty string matching `/^[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*\z/`), so the operator just returns that initial value.