# Encoding: use 'utf8'

Tags: perl, utf-8, character-encoding, encode

Can I omit the `use 'utf8'`-pragma when I am already using `use encoding 'utf8'`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use Encode qw(is_utf8);

use encoding 'utf8';


my %hash = ( '☺' => "☺", '\x{263a}' => "\x{263a}", 'ä' => "ä", 'a' => "a" );
for my $key ( sort keys %hash ) {
    say "UTF8 flag is turned on in the STRING $key" if is_utf8( $hash{$key} );
    say "UTF8 flag is NOT turned on in the STRING $key" if not is_utf8( $hash{$key} );
}
```

Comment: See Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492838/why-do-my-perl-tests-fail-with-use-encoding-utf8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`use encoding` is official discouraged.** The module is deprecated because it causes very weird behaviour. Instead, you should use the following:

```
use utf8;                             # Source code is UTF-8
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';  # STDIN,STDOUT,STDERR are UTF-8.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but make sure you are familiar with the [CAVEATS](http://perldoc.perl.org/encoding.html#CAVEATS) in the perldoc.