# Perl's use encoding pragma breaking UTF strings

Tags: perl

I have a problem with Perl and Encoding pragma.

(I use utf-8 everywhere, in input, output, the perl scripts themselves. I don't want to use other encoding, never ever.)

However. When I write

```
binmode(STDOUT, ':utf8');
use utf8;
$r = "\x{ed}";
print $r;
```

I see the string "[í](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%8D)" (which is what I want - and what is U+00ED unicode char). But when I add the "use encoding" pragma like this

```
binmode(STDOUT, ':utf8');
use utf8;
use encoding 'utf8';
$r = "\x{ed}";
print $r;
```

all I see is a box character. Why?

Moreover, when I add Data::Dumper and let the Dumper print the new string like this

```
binmode(STDOUT, ':utf8');
use utf8;
use encoding 'utf8';
$r = "\x{ed}";
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($r);
```

I see that perl **changed the string** to `"\x{fffd}"`. Why?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492838/why-do-my-perl-tests-fail-with-use-encoding-utf8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`use encoding 'utf8'` is broken. Rather than interpreting `\x{ed}` as the code point U+00ED, it interprets it as the single byte 237 and then tries to interpret that as UTF-8. Which of course fails, so it winds up replacing it with the replacement character U+FFFD, literally "�".

Just stick with `use utf8` to specify that your source is in UTF-8, and `binmode` or the [open pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html) to specify the encoding for your file handles.

Comment: Oh... OK. I can't claim I understand the reason for the reinterpreting, but there are far, far more weird things in perl. Thanks

Comment: As far as I can tell, the reason is that `use encoding` was designed so people could write `use encoding 'euc-jp'; $r = "\xF1\xD1\xF1\xCC";` and have it interpreted "correctly". But that would mean you'd have to write your UTF-8 string in the same style, as `$r = "\xC3\xAD";`. Which then gets confusing when combined with Perl's native support for UTF-8 like `$r = "\x{200b}";`, escapes with codes 0x80-0xff are interpreted differently from escapes with codes 0x100 and up.

Comment: Yeah, Perl's support for 8-bit locales (`use encoding`, `use locale`) should be kept at the other end of a very long stick.

Answer (score 5):

Your actual code needs neither `use encoding` nor `use utf8` to run properly -- the only thing it depends on is the encoding layer on `STDOUT`.

```
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
print "\xed";
```

is an equally valid complete program that does what you want.

`use utf8` should be used only if you have UTF-8 in literal strings in your program -- e.g. if you had written

```
my $r = "í";
```

then `use utf8` would cause that string to be interpreted as the single character U+00ED instead of the series of bytes C3 AD.

`use encoding` should never be used, especially by someone who likes Unicode. If you want the encoding of stdin/out to be changed you should use `-C` or `PERLUNICODE` or binmode them yourself, and if you want other handles to be automatically openhed with encoding layers you should `use`[`open`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/open).

Comment: hobbs: yes, I have actual UTF-8 literals in my code (in regular expressions). Thanks.